# insert items in table and Sub table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I am trying to write a single-page app with the below details, but unable to complete all. (shared the code below)

- Header input fields.
- Items input(can be using modal) and View(as table)
- Sub-items input(using modal) and view(as table) , each items can or cannot have sub-items.
- Create/Submit button will send all data to an end-point using Ajax.

sub table data will be added by input form through a bootstrap modal.

[image]

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
  
<div class="container">  
  
  <form>  
   
<table class="table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control"  id='txtCustomerNumb' placeholder="Customer Number" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtCustomerName' placeholder="Customer Name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDeliverTo' placeholder="Deliver To" /></td>
<td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDriverName' placeholder="Driver Name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDriverContact' placeholder="Driver Contact" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtVehNumber' placeholder="Vehicle No." /></td>
<td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="txtDeliverTo" placeholder="Exit Point">
    <option value="">Select Exit Point</option>
    <option value="Exit_Point_1">Exit Point 1</option>
    <option value="Exit_Point_2">Exit Point 2</option>
    <option value="Exit_Point_3">Exit Point 3</option> 
  </select>
            
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDeliverTo' placeholder="Deliver To" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtExitType' placeholder="Type Of Exit" /></td>
<td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>   
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">  
  <label>Name:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="Smith" required="">  
</div>  
  
<div class="form-group col-md-6">  
  <label>Email:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="smith@abc.com" required="">  
 
 </div>  
 <div class="form-group col-md-2" style="padding-top: 23px;">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save-btn">Add</button> 
 </div>
  </div>
  </form>  
  <br/>  
  <table class="table table-bordered data-table">  
<thead>  
  <th>Name</th>  
  <th>Email</th>  
  <th width="200px">Action</th>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
  
</tbody>  
  </table>  
 
</div>  
 
<script type="text/javascript">  
 
$("form").submit(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();  
    var email = $("input[name='email']").val();  
   
    $(".data-table tbody").append("<tr data-name='"+name+"' data-email='"+email+"'><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+email+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");  
  
    $("input[name='name']").val('');  
    $("input[name='email']").val('');  
});  
 
$("body").on("click", ".btn-delete", function(){  
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();  
});  
  
$("body").on("click", ".btn-edit", function(){  
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name');  
    var email = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-email');  
  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").html('<input name="edit_name" value="'+name+'">');  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").html('<input name="edit_email" value="'+email+'">');  
  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").prepend("<button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-update'>Update</button><button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-cancel'>Cancel</button>")  
    $(this).hide();  
});  
 
$("body").on("click", ".btn-cancel", function(){  
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name');  
    var email = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-email');  
  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(name);  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text(email);  
 
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-edit").show();  
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-update").remove();  
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-cancel").remove();  
});  
 
$("body").on("click", ".btn-update", function(){  
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name='edit_name']").val();  
    var email = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name='edit_email']").val();  
  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(name);  
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text(email);  
   
    $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name', name);  
    $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-email', email);  
  
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-edit").show();  
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-cancel").remove();  
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-update").remove();  
});  
  
</script>  
   
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the code of the sub-table, and how should a user display it?

Comment: that is missing I tried but not working for me.

Comment: What have you tried? It's ok (and even required by [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to post your failed try, and it would help us guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example. This is using the latest Bootstrap version.

```js
$(function() {

  function addItem(data, table) {
    var row = $("<tr>").data("item", data).appendTo(table);
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      $("<td>").html(v).appendTo(row);
    });
    $("<td>").appendTo(row);
    $.each(["update", "cancel", "edit", "delete"], function(i, el) {
      $("<button>", {
        class: "btn btn-sm btn-" + el
      }).html(el[0].toUpperCase() + el.substr(1)).appendTo("td:last", row);
    });
    $(".btn-edit, .btn-update", row).addClass("btn-info");
    $(".btn-cancel", row).addClass("btn-warning");
    $(".btn-delete", row).addClass("btn-danger");
    $("button:lt(2)", row).hide();
  }

  function editItem(row) {
    var item = $(row).data("item");
    var keys = Object.keys(item);
    $("td:not(:last)", row).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).html(
        $("<input>", {
          name: "item_" + keys[i],
          type: (i < 2) ? "text" : "number",
          value: item[keys[i]]
        })
      );
    });
    $("button", row).show();
    $("button:gt(1)", row).hide();
  }

  function updateItem(row) {
    var newItem = {
      name: $("input[name='item_name']", row).val(),
      desc: $("input[name='item_desc']", row).val(),
      qnty: $("input[name='item_qnty']", row).val()
    };
    var keys = Object.keys(newItem);
    $(row).data("item", newItem);
    $("td:not(:last)", row).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).empty().html(newItem[keys[i]]);
    });
    $("button", row).show();
    $("button:lt(2)", row).hide();
  }

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = {
      name: $("input[name='item']").val(),
      desc: $("input[name='description']").val(),
      qnty: $("input[name='quantity']").val()
    };
    addItem(item, "table.data-table");

    $("input[name='item'], input[name='description'], input[name='quantity']").val('');
  });

  $(".table").on("click", ".btn-delete", function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this row?")) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });

  $(".table").on("click", ".btn-edit", function() {
    editItem($(this).closest("tr"));
  });

  $(".table").on("click", ".btn-cancel", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var item = $(row).data("item");
    var keys = Object.keys(item);
    $("td:not(:last)", row).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).html(item[keys[i]]);
    });
    $("button", row).show();
    $("button:lt(2)", row).hide();
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".btn-update", function() {
    updateItem($(this).closest("tr"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-10">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtCustomerNumb' placeholder="Customer Number" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtCustomerName' placeholder="Customer Name" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDeliverTo' placeholder="Deliver To" /></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDriverName' placeholder="Driver Name" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDriverContact' placeholder="Driver Contact" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtVehNumber' placeholder="Vehicle No." /></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="txtDeliverTo" placeholder="Exit Point">
                  <option value="">Select Exit Point</option>
                  <option value="Exit_Point_1">Exit Point 1</option>
                  <option value="Exit_Point_2">Exit Point 2</option>
                  <option value="Exit_Point_3">Exit Point 3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDeliverTo' placeholder="Deliver To" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtExitType' placeholder="Type Of Exit" /></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<form>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-2">
      <input type="text" name="item" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save-btn">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered data-table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see there are a lot of functions that can be created if you choose. The `cancel` event is an example without using functions.

You will want to use `.closest()` to find the parent row. You can then properly select elements from the `row` as needed.

It did not make a lot of sense to add and remove buttons, better to just hide them when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap-Table, here is an example of what you are looking to do:

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcome.html#view-source

In this case you can have a table with more options, also you can use ajax to load, paginate and execute actions to the data.

Other option is inside your table you can insert a subtable with javascript.